# How to calculate VAT on already given daily rate?

Tags: contracts, contracting, taxes

As a contractor in the UK, I have been offered a daily rate of 500 from the recruitment agency who is the intermediary between me (Ltd) and the client.
Do I add 20% VAT on top of that, i.e. charge 600 at the end, or do I absorb the VAT therefore I am getting net approx 416 and the 20% goes to VAT and still charge 500 for my services?

Comment: Because it is Saturday, plus someone else may benefit from this question in the future.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about taxes and op could just check contract to find out what the rate is

Answer (score 4):

VAT is a legal tax requirement, it is not something that you charge depending on the customer's mood.

VAT certification is a requirement at above a certain income level, although it is not an explanation as to why VAT was not collected. To whit, you need to collect VAT, and any billing you have made while NOT VAT certified still needs VAT to be collected.

Some customers will not pay VAT if there is no VAT certification, but this is not correct - technically they should still be billed VAT, in reality once you are VAT certified reach out and ask them for the VAT to be paid.

Finally, you collect VAT for HMRC, but HMRC allows you to retain some of that, for your troubles. As a services company, your VAT rate in 2017 is 15.5%, as a newly registered VAT company you get a 1% point deduction for your first year, so it is 14.5%.

You will still collect 20%, and probably think you pass on 14.5%, keeping 5.5%. This is not the case.

Your daily rate is 500, you charge VAT on top of that, as a separate line item of 100 a day.

You then fill in the confusing VAT form - it is needlessly poorly worded, don't pay an accountant to do this HMRC are deceptively helpful in the phone - and pay 87 a day VAT (14.5 of 600), keeping 13 for yourself.

Also, you don't get to deduct VAT charged to your company, unless the VAT amount charged is above a certain amount - check with HMRC for this. If you want to start deducting VAT, you need to change from the services level (ie keeping 13 a day) to the more intensive deductions method, which will only save you more if you are spending a lot on VAT payments (compare a grocery store to a services company - the store buys goods then sells them, each good bought costs VAT. You have no VAT to deduct, so...)

Answer (score -1):

Fact: Some contractors charge VAT, some don't (depending on your annual revenue). Since 99.99% of their customers are not private citizens but companies, their customers don't care about it.

When you charge a rate of £500, it is understood that this is either £500 with no VAT to be paid, or £500 plus VAT. That £600 bill including VAT doesn't cost the company more than the £500 exclusive VAT, because they deduct the £100 from their own VAT bill.

Charge £500 plus VAT. If you are VAT registered. If not, charge £500.

PS. OP states "I will be VAT registered". Until the moment where you are VAT registered, it is illegal for you to charge VAT. You can voluntarily register at any time, you MUST register when your revenue was £82,000 in twelve consecutive months. In your case, at some point after 8 months.

Comment: I will be VAT registered as I will be higher than the annual threshold revenue. So it'll be 500 plus 20% I guess, totaling to 600. So the VAT is paid only to be returned as I understand.